# Selenium-webdriver js browser logs just [object Object]

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the function takeLogs working on Selenium-webdriver in Javascript as such:

```
var takeLogs = function(driver, fname) {
  var dir = createDirectory('logs');
  driver.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(logs) {
    var fullpath = path.join(dir, fname)+'.txt';
    fs.writeFile(fullpath, logs, function(err) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    });
  })
};
```

However, when I look at the generated text files, they just say `[object Object]` or `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` etc...

How can I get the actual expanded logs? I'm using chromedriver, if that helps.

Comment: Try logging `err.message`.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding you, sorry. If I make line 3's callback take `(logs, err)` and put `console.log(err)` right after, there is no `err` object. If I just put `console.log(err)` in the `fs.writeFile` callback, like before the `if` statement, it just logs `null` because there is no error.

Comment: No, I'm simply saying that you should try `console.log(err.message)` instead of `console.log(err)`.

Comment: I made that change, but nothing is logged in the console because `err` never happens, so `if (err)` evals to false. The `err` in the `fs.writeFile` callback is if the file writing experiences an error, and the filewriting works fine. It's just writing `[object Object]`, but I want it to write the logs, which I image are in that object.

Comment: In writing that response, I decided to `console.log` the `logs` arg and I indeed get the stuff I want: `[ Entry {
    level: Level { name_: 'SEVERE', value_: 1000 },
    message: 'http://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1 - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED',
    timestamp: 1508957410156,
    type: '' } ]`. So it's just a matter of writing it correctly! Thanks for getting me there at least!

Answer (score 0):

Something happens with `fs.writeFile` that parses the logs in an undesired manner.

Simply `console.log`ing the `logs` indeed shows the contents of the logs.